# Do Passive Mobs need Sunlight?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play minecraft pe with the 0.9.0 update. I made a barn and I have many animals inside but I have not finished the roof. I dont know if they will live or not without sun, or trapped in a building. Can I keep them inside a barn with a roof or will I need glass so there is some sunlight?

Answer (score 3):

[Passive mobs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mobs#Passive) are not damaged by sunlight or lack of it, so you can keep your animals in a barn with a roof without worrying about them dying.